# I can't get the right answer between live or living on a test

Tags: present-tense, verb-forms

> **Living** with a foreign family can be a good way to learn a language.

or

> **Live** with a foreign family can be a good way to learn a language.

Answer (score 4):

Your basic structure is

> [[Something]] *can be* [[something else]]

`Subject - verb* - object.`  What can be the subject of a sentence?  Either a noun or a phrase that acts as a noun.

In this case the subject is going to be a *gerund* which is a type of noun made by adding *-ing* to a verb:  *Liv-ing.*  In this case, we think of *living* as  a something - an abstract something, but a thing, not an action.

> Living can be a good way to learn a language.

Now we have a fully grammatical sentence - but it doesn't really make sense.  Not just any *living* is good for learning a language - we need to modify what kind of *living* it is.  We'll turn the noun into a *noun phrase* by adding a prepositional phrase to it.

> Living *with a foreign family* can be a good way to learn a language.

Note that since the noun is a gerund in this case, we could also call it a *gerund phrase.*

---

*Live* is a verb, not a noun, so it doesn't work as the subject of the sentence.

---

One other form that could have worked, if it were an option on the test is the non-gerund noun "*life*." This sentence would have a very similar meaning to the one that uses *living*:

> Life with a foreign family can be a good way to learn a language.

---

<sub>* *Can be* is actually a modal verb phrase.  *Can* is the modal verb, and *be* is the bare infinitive of the verb *to be.*</sub>

Answer (score 4):

One of the tricky things about English is that many verb forms are the same.

Live can be an imperative

> live well!

Or a present tense

> I live in Egypt

Or an infinitive

> I prefer to live near my family

Living can be an active participle

> I was living in Tehran at that time

Or a gerund (verbal noun)

> Living abroad is exciting

In your sentence, **can be** is a verb and requires a noun phrase as a subject. You can use a gerund or an infinitive to form a noun phrase:

> Living with a foreign family can be a good way to learn a language
>
> To live with a foreign family can be a good way to learn a language

The first (living) is the most idiomatic way of saying this.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, the infinitive is "to live," not "live," but good explanation.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai, agreed: I introduced it to lead up to explaining that you could also use an infinitive to make a correct sentence. Also, **can be** is not a verb... but let's just keep it simple..

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Not quite: *live* is the unmarked infinitive, employed for instance with modal verbs: *The doctors believe that he will live*.

Comment: Well, in his example sentence, "to live" is an infinitive, not a collocation of a preposition and a form of the verb, was my point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *live*, but you'd need to restructure the sentence somehow:

- Living with a foreign family can be a good way to learn a language.
- Live with a foreign family – that can be a good way to learn a language.

Comment: The second one sound like an imperative to me. Did you mean, "**Life** with a foreign family"?

Comment: @MrLister I meant the imperative, to distinguish it from the gerund.